# $.AJAX() POST always success, even if I post to www.google.com

Tags: jquery

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'www.google.com.hk'/* this.options.url */,
            type: 'POST',
            // dataType: this.options.dataType,
            data: fd,
            xhr: function() {
                var xhrObj = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                xhrObj.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event){
                    // using ProgressEvent API
                    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ProgressEvent
                    console.log('event.loaded / event.total: ');
                    console.log(event.loaded +' / ' + event.total);
                    if(event.lengthComputable) {
                        var percentage = event.loaded / event.total * 100;
                        widget.onProgressUpdate(percentage);
                    }
                }, false);
                return xhrObj;
            },
            processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
                contentType: false,  // tell jQuery not to set contentType
            success: function(data, message, xhr) {
                alert('success');
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, errMsg) {
                alert('error');
            },
            complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
                alert('complete');
            }
        });
    }
```

My purpose is to learn to use '`progress`' event during ajax upload file.

I am POSTing is a 40MB video file to www.google.com.hk using `$.ajax()`. The result is success. The URL seems doesn't matter. Can you please tell me what I missed? 
[image]

I think this problem has something to do with:

```
processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
```

but if I delete this line, the ajax request always giving this error: `"Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation"`.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

You're not actually sending a request to Google but to your own site.
Unless you add a protocol to the url (like `https:`) the url will be considered relative.
My first thought was that you should get a 404 error, but then I thought about url rewriting and routing which may consume a bad url without issuing an error.

Answer (score 1):

Google returns `200 OK`, that's why `success` is triggered. `error` will be triggered when the remote URL returns any HTTP error code (e.g. 404)

Comment: I replace 'www.google.com.ch' with '/jjjjjjjj', it is still a sucess.

Comment: For whatever reason, your website doesn't throw 404. It's not jQuery's fault.

Comment: oh yes, I didn't set header 404 code when returning 404 page. That's why it is always success. Thanks~